# Unable to load bootstrap with Node-sass, bootstrap-sass

Tags: css, node.js, twitter-bootstrap

I'm on a old/new project based on node/express where boostrap source was painfully copy-pasted (and hacked).
I want to use bootstrap package to be more maintainable. But, after adding bootstrap-sass and node-sass, I face this error:

Here's the error

```
in /vagrant/sass/theme.scss:28:1
Error: File to import not found or unreadable: bootstrap/variables
Parent style sheet: /vagrant/sass/theme.scss
    at options.error (/vagrant/node_modules/node-sass/lib/index.js:277:32)
  source: /vagrant/sass/vendor/bootstrap-datepicker/css/bootstrap-datepicker3.min.scss
  dest: /vagrant/public/css/vendor/bootstrap-datepicker/css/bootstrap-datepicker3.min.css
  read: /vagrant/public/css/vendor/bootstrap-datepicker/css/bootstrap-datepicker3.min.css
  source: /vagrant/sass/theme.scss
  dest: /vagrant/public/css/theme.css
  read: /vagrant/public/css/theme.css
  error: File to import not found or unreadable: bootstrap/variables
Parent style sheet: /vagrant/sass/theme.scss

in /vagrant/sass/theme.scss:28:1
Error: File to import not found or unreadable: bootstrap/variables
Parent style sheet: /vagrant/sass/theme.scss
    at options.error (/vagrant/node_modules/node-sass/lib/index.js:277:32)
```

server.js

```
app.use(
  sass({
    src: __dirname + '/sass',
    dest: __dirname + '/public/css',
    prefix: '/css',
    // outputStyle: 'compressed',
    debug: true,
  })
);
```

package.json:

```
"dependencies": {
  "bcrypt-nodejs": "0.0.3",
  "body-parser": "^1.13.1",
  "bootstrap-sass": "^3.3.6",
  "connect-flash": "^0.1.1",
  "cookie-parser": "^1.3.5",
  "express": "^4.12.4",
  "express-session": "^1.11.3",
  "mysql": "^2.7.0",
  "node-sass": "^3.4.2",
  "node-sass-middleware": "^0.9.7",
  "passport": "^0.2.2",
  "passport-facebook": "^2.0.0",
  "passport-google-oauth": "^0.2.0",
  "passport-local": "^1.0.0",
  "passport-twitter": "^1.0.3",
  "randomstring": "^1.1.3",
  "sendgrid": "^1.9.2",
  "sequelize": "^3.9.0",
  "sequelize-fixtures": "^0.4.8",
  "shelljs": "^0.5.3",
  "swig": "^1.4.2"
},
"devDependencies": {
  "eslint": "^1.10.3",
  "gulp": "^3.9.0",
  "gulp-zip": "^3.0.2",
  "jake": "^8.0.12",
  "minimist": "^1.2.0",
  "node-sass": "^3.3.3",
  "node-sass-middleware": "^0.9.6"
}
```

theme.scss

```
/*!
 * Bootstrap v3.3.6 (http://getbootstrap.com)
 * Copyright 2011-2015 Twitter, Inc.
 * Licensed under MIT (https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/LICENSE)
 */

// Core variables and mixins
@import "bootstrap/variables";
@import "bootstrap/mixins";

// Reset and dependencies
@import "bootstrap/normalize";
@import "bootstrap/print";
@import "bootstrap/glyphicons";

// Core CSS
@import "bootstrap/scaffolding";
@import "bootstrap/type";
@import "bootstrap/code";
@import "bootstrap/grid";
@import "bootstrap/tables";
@import "bootstrap/forms";
@import "bootstrap/buttons";

// Components
@import "bootstrap/component-animations";
@import "bootstrap/dropdowns";
@import "bootstrap/button-groups";
@import "bootstrap/input-groups";
@import "bootstrap/navs";
@import "bootstrap/navbar";
@import "bootstrap/breadcrumbs";
@import "bootstrap/pagination";
@import "bootstrap/pager";
@import "bootstrap/labels";
@import "bootstrap/badges";
@import "bootstrap/jumbotron";
@import "bootstrap/thumbnails";
@import "bootstrap/alerts";
@import "bootstrap/progress-bars";
@import "bootstrap/media";
@import "bootstrap/list-group";
@import "bootstrap/panels";
@import "bootstrap/responsive-embed";
@import "bootstrap/wells";
@import "bootstrap/close";

// Components w/ JavaScript
@import "bootstrap/modals";
@import "bootstrap/tooltip";
@import "bootstrap/popovers";
@import "bootstrap/carousel";

// Utility classes
@import "bootstrap/utilities";
@import "bootstrap/responsive-utilities";
```

I'm new to node, coming from Rails where setupping bootstrap with sass was really easy. Let me know if you need additional files/info about the project.

Thank you for help!

Comment: Works when replacing "bootstrap" by node module path "../node_modules/bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/_bootstrap".

But i'm not sure it's the good way to do it. Could you please confirm it to me?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I had a similar issue when importing `bootstrap-sass` to a React/Webpack project, but the solution is the same. In your main scss file (theme.scss), you need @import individual mixins via the relative paths inside the node_modules package minus the `node_modules` path segment.

If you are pulling individual features then you need to change the `@import "bootstrap/feature"` path to reflect the path of every feature you want to use in the bootstrap-sass package. Also note the preceding `~`in the path, which resolves an error for navigating the to SCSS files.

```
@import "~bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/variables";
```

Another gotcha, if you are pulling in the glyphicons you are going to need to set the `$icon-font-path` to point to the fonts folder in the package, or else the server will error out for finding those files.

```
$icon-font-path: "~bootstrap-sass/assets/fonts/bootstrap/";
@import "bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/glyphicons";
```

If you just want to use everything in the package, you can just set the icon-font-path and pull in all the styles like so in your theme.scss file.

```
// Bootstrap
$icon-font-path: "~bootstrap-sass/assets/fonts/bootstrap/";
@import "~bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/_bootstrap.scss";
```

Comment: Works great! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Had to use this in a react project, fwiw: `$icon-font-path: "~bootstrap-sass/assets/fonts/bootstrap/";
@import "../node_modules/bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/_bootstrap.scss";`

Comment: This doesn't seem to be working anymore, using bootstrap-sass@3.3.7 and node-sass@4.5.3. The `~` is treated like a regular filename character apparently.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar issue when importing bootstrap-sass in angular and gulp-sass. in my project problem resolve with

```
"./node_modules/bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/variables"
```